# Unable to convert os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1] to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, operating-system

I am trying to create a face recognition software using OpenCV, but the code I found in the library is made in Python 2. Is there a Python 3 version of this?

Here's the link: https://github.com/thecodacus/Face-Recognition

I already have a folder for dataset and trainer.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples,ids

print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/FacialRecognition/02_face_training.py", line 46, in <module>
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/FacialRecognition/02_face_training.py", line 36, in getImagesAndLabels
id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'User'
```

Comment: What is `imagePath` in the code you posted?

Comment: Please show us *your* code.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce your error.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: as of 2022, I have learned from my mistake so please stop viewing this question as it is not reproduceable. I'm sorry to whoever wasted their time here, I know better now.

Answer (score 0):

On that repository there's a `dataSet` directory, with a file named like:

```
In [665]: name='Face-Recognition/dataSet/face-1.1.jpg'
```

Applied to that name, your code sample does:

```
In [668]: os.path.split(name)                                                                          
Out[668]: ('Face-Recognition/dataSet', 'face-1.1.jpg')
In [669]: os.path.split(name)[-1]                                                                      
Out[669]: 'face-1.1.jpg'
In [670]: os.path.split(name)[-1].split('.')                                                           
Out[670]: ['face-1', '1', 'jpg']
In [671]: os.path.split(name)[-1].split('.')[1]                                                        
Out[671]: '1'
In [672]: int(os.path.split(name)[-1].split('.')[1])                                                   
Out[672]: 1
```

Apparently your file has a different name format, one that includes 'User' in a slot where this code expects a number.

You need to correct the file name, or change this parsing code.

Answer (score 0):

The image name which you got in the dataset are as `User.*somename*`, so remove User from all the image names.

Answer (score 0):

try to change format images is 'face.1.1.jpg'
then you can split the dot with this code

```
faceID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[2])
```

Answer (score -1):

This did the job for me:

```
Id=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[0])
```